# Can one work on Chol Hamoed if they enjoy working?

Tags: halacha

The title says it all. If someone simply enjoys working, regardless of the money, can they work during Chol Hamo'ed. This is especially relevant now when they'd just be bored otherwise. Would working be ok in this case?

Comment: Probably depends on what your work entails../

Comment: The whole point is not that you enjoy working, but that working at a job is not proper. Of course you enjoy it, but you should enjoy learning torah also.

Comment: I edited the question. It shouldn't be problematic anymore.